# What does this T-with-a-bar-in-the-middle accidental mean?

Tags: theory, notation, accidentals

I've never seen it before, and I found it on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeihEzz9Tpw). I know it's an accidental, though.

[image: short horizontal bar with downward stem containing diagonal crossbar]

Comment: A timestamp would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The video indicates that the score was created in MuseScore 3. Looking through the accidentals in that software, this one stands for "raise by one equal tempered quarter". Basically, it's a quarter-tone sharp.

[image: Accidental with tooltip in MuseScore 3]

Comment: I recently heard this glyph called a *half-sharp*.

Comment: @ToddWilcox the traditional half sharp lacks the horizontal crossbar at the top of the vertical stroke, which I suppose is intended to specify equal temperament as it resembles the letter _T._

Comment: @ToddWilcox on reflection, though, I do find this symbol to be a bit useless.  First, it's hard to read.  Note how the crossbar is almost lost by its proximity to the staff line.  The tenuto marks don't help. Second, it's probably TMI. If there are no other places in the piece that use a different variety of quarter tone, just specify 24-TET and use a normal half-sharp symbol.  If so, do you have musicians who can play them accurately?  If so, can you really hear the difference?

Comment: @phoog  I vote we create a scale containing neither 'equal' nor 'just' tempered intervals, but rather  'evil'  and 'unjust' .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "Concerto in C Maladjusted for Kazoo and Convicted Felon"